# Data block Fortran 77 clarification

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am trying to access a data block, the way it is define is as follows

```
      DATA NAME /'X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8','X9','10','11',00028650
     1'12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24'/ 00028660
```

The code is on paper. Note this is an old code, the only thing i am trying to do is understand how the array is being indexed. I am not trying to compile it.

The way it is accessed is as follows

```
I = 0
Loop
   I = I + 1
   write (06,77) (NAME(J,I),J=1,4)  //this is inside a write statement. 
end loop                            //77 is a format statement.
```

Not sure how it is being indexed, if you guys can shed some light that would be great.

Comment: You will need to show the declaration of `name` for us to understand this fully, and give full code not pseudo-code.  However, I guess that you have an _IO implied do loop_.

Comment: @francescalus I edited the code to the best I could. Please look at it. The names for talking purposes are gonna be two characters. That's what I have in the code, I just changed it to numbers for the purpose of this question.

Comment: Do you have something like `character*2 name(4,6)`?

Comment: @francescalus no, not that I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `(expr, intvar=int1,int2[,int3])` widely refers to an *implied DO loop*.  There are several places where such a thing may occur, and an input/output statement is one such place.

An implied DO loop evaluates the expression `expr` with the do control integer variable `intvar` sequentially taking the values initially `int1` in steps of `int3` until the value `int2` is reached/passed.  This loop control is exactly as one would find in a do loop statement.

In the case of the question, the expression is `name(j,i)`, the integer variable `j` is the loop variable, taking values between the bounds `1` and `4`.  [The step size `int3` is not provided so is treated as `1`.]  The output statement is therefore exactly like

```
write(6,77) name(1,i), name(2,i), name(3,i), name(4,i)
```

as we should note that elements of the implied loop are expanded in order.  `i` itself comes from the loop containing this output statement.

`name` here may refer to a function, but given the presence of a `data` statement initializing it, it must somehow be declared as a rank-2 (character) array.  The initialization is not otherwise important.

Comment: can you explain further in the case of i = 1, what would name(1,i) equals to and so on and why? What is throwing me off is it looks like a 2D array.